# What is the correct way to express "select all when nothing is specified in parameter"?

Tags: rest, design-patterns, parameters, null, nullable

Let's say we have an HTTP endpoint to get all elements by name?

GET /elements?name={name}

`{name}` can have a value of CSV or be absent

```
valid:

  GET /elements?name=Bill,Mary,Ann
  GET /elements?name=Mike
  GET /elements

invalid:
  GET /elements?name=
```

Somehow we find out in controller that `name` is not passed. We know that the contract implies to return all values for `elements`. Possible decisions on further actions (I've seen in different projects) are:

- using a NULL or a "dummy" substitution like a secret char sequence "!@$@%#$" and juggling them in database while building a query
- using `if (present) { executeQueryA } else { executeQueryB }` logic

I am not sure I like either of these approaches, because when there is **more than one optional filter** these designs become unmaintainable. Something makes me believe that there is a better way  to handle the situation.

**What would be a proper design on back-end and in database query to handle the case "select all" when nothing is given? Just a general idea and some pseudo-code will be much appreciated.**

Comment: It sounds like this question is about how to build a SQL query in a clean way, not really about REST or urls.

Comment: @Evert you are right. And additionally I would say it is about translation (or building a bridge between REST and DB). Obviously, the described intention can be clearly expressed in URL (not only for REST), but code of the internal mechanics ("translation") is usually unproportionally tricky. I want to understand whether this complexity is essential or accidental.

Comment: I've written a ton of code that had to deal with an 'optional filter' situation, so it's not at all unique to urls or REST and you'd run into this any time. You should try to quantify what's painful about just combining parts of queries and solve this.